# how to display multiple nav bar tab horizontal on click checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how to display multiple nav bar tab horizontal on click checkbox

what i am trying to do that when i click on checkbox then show navbar and when i click on uncheck box then its hide.

in here below my code what I m try to create functionality its work fine. but its show and hide nav bar in vertically but i want to achieve in one line (horizontal)

but i am not able to achieve i m stuck on that when i click on checkbox1 and checkbox2 its show in one line in horizontal. But its not happen in my code.

My goal when i click on checkbox1 and checkbox2 both then  navbar tab display in one line .but in my code when i click both checkbox 1 and 2 then its show vertically.

my expectation result look like this something https://ibb.co/D16nBNH

anybody body help me this issue.

```js
function addDay(e) {
  document.getElementById(e.value).style.display = e.checked ? "initial" : "none";
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" value="lundi" id="lundiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />1
  <input type="checkbox" value="mardi" id="mardiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />2
  <input type="checkbox" value="mercredi" id="mercrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />3
  <input type="checkbox" value="jeudi" id="jeudiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />4
  <input type="checkbox" value="vendredi" id="vendrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />5
  <input type="checkbox" value="samedi" id="samediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />6
  <input type="checkbox" value="dimanche" id="dimancheCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />7
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="lundi">
  
    <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
     
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mardi">
      <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
     
    </div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mercredi">Some content3</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="jeudi">Some content4</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="vendredi">Some content5</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="samedi">Some content6</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="dimanche">Some content6</div>
</div>
```

its not happen in my code how can we do that

any help its vey thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change from `.container` to `.container-2` class and a `display:flex` to it to get all the **nav-tabs** in horizontal line.

```js
function addDay(e) {
  document.getElementById(e.value).style.display = e.checked ? "initial" : "none";
}
```

```css
.container-2{
display:flex}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" value="lundi" id="lundiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />1
  <input type="checkbox" value="mardi" id="mardiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />2
  <input type="checkbox" value="mercredi" id="mercrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />3
  <input type="checkbox" value="jeudi" id="jeudiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />4
  <input type="checkbox" value="vendredi" id="vendrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />5
  <input type="checkbox" value="samedi" id="samediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />6
  <input type="checkbox" value="dimanche" id="dimancheCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />7
</div>

<div class="container-2">
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="lundi">
  
    <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
     
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mardi">
      <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
     
    </div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mercredi">Some content3</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="jeudi">Some content4</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="vendredi">Some content5</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="samedi">Some content6</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="dimanche">Some content6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have one more small doubt in here this is my code link https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GOEZOJFL798Q  when i click on checkbox2 then toggle tab colour is coming in upfront on add new button

Comment: how can we do that i m stuck n here.https://ibb.co/6BWKS5c this is image link what i try to achive and this my code link what i try to do like this https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GOEZOJFL798Q

Comment: can u help m in this??